# White gaps dissapear or appear on different screen sizes when containing div elements in div elements

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#window {
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height: 850px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 850px;
    display: grid;
    border: 3px solid black;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr 0.2fr;
}

#window>div {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#window div:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: black;

}

#content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
}

#movieSelect {
    border-top: 3px solid black;
}

#movieDetails {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

}


#control {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(153, 65, 65, 0.83);
}

#mainForm {
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
}

#mainInput {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#mainInput:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 242, 0.306);
}

/* //focus doesn't change specified background color */

#btn {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#btn:active {
    background-color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

#movieSelect {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;

}

#movieSelect>button {
    min-width: 118.8px;
    max-width: 118.8px
}

#movieSelect>button:focus {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="window">
            <div id="image">
                <img id="mainImage" src="https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/333/834110.jpg"
                    alt="">
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div id="movieDetails">
                    <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3First">Name
                        <br> The Johnsons sdasd sad asdasasd as das as
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Second">Rating:
                        <br> 89.92
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Third">Release Date:
                        <br> 2012-12-02
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Fourth">More Details:
                        <br> <a href="">https://www.tv-wot.com</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div id="movieSelect">
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="control">
                <form id="mainForm" action="">
                    <input id="mainInput" type="text" name="movieSearch">
                    <button id="btn">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello! I am getting these ugly little white gaps when containing elements and they really just make everything very ugly and buggy looking. For example there's a random gap at the right of the black background where the image is which appears and disappears. There is another above the buttons. Also another css questions. Why is the input textarea so dark when focused even though I chose a very bright color. Thank you!

Comment: The dark color on button focus comes from the opacity, try `rgb(0, 255, 242)` to see your color

Comment: Do those white lines come and go as you zoom in and out? If so it's a known problem caused by the system 'leaving behind' some screen pixels when it's dealing with part pixels (modern screens have several screen pixels per CSS pixel). Bit like a rounding error. There are (slightly hacky) workarounds. Are you able to alter the HTML?

Comment: @Cédric Yeah I saw that but the problem is that I want to apply a very very light color but here I either get a dark color that doesn't represent the color or chose or with max opacity you get an extremely over-saturated color.

Comment: @AHaworth Yeah I can. You got any suggestions?
Edit: Oh lol just saw your post below, thanks lad

Comment: @legendman `rgb(0, 255, 242)` correspond to a very light blue color. The dark color comes from that you overides the default input brackground so the light brown color is applied to the input, and then you apply your light blue color with opacity wich renders this dark color.

Comment: If you want a specific color, make sure you don't use an opacity with some other background color applied or it will change the color you see

Answer (score 1):

These are screen (not whole CSS) pixels sort of left behind when the system works out how to map part pixels (one CSS pixel on a modern screen can map to several screen pixels).

This snippet hacks round the problem by putting a pseudo before element on the image's containing div which has a black background and which is just slightly bigger than the element itself.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#window {
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 850px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 850px;
  display: grid;
  border: 3px solid black;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr 0.2fr;
}

#window>div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#window div:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

#image::before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
}

#movieSelect {
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}

#movieDetails {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#control {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(153, 65, 65, 0.83);
}

#mainForm {
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

#mainInput {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mainInput:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 242, 0.306);
}


/* //focus doesn't change specified background color */

#btn {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#btn:active {
  background-color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

#movieSelect {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#movieSelect>button {
  min-width: 118.8px;
  max-width: 118.8px
}

#movieSelect>button:focus {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="window">
      <div id="image">
        <img id="mainImage" src="https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/333/834110.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        <div id="movieDetails">
          <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3First">Name
            <br> The Johnsons sdasd sad asdasasd as das as
          </h3>
          <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Second">Rating:
            <br> 89.92
          </h3>
          <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Third">Release Date:
            <br> 2012-12-02
          </h3>
          <h3 class="h3Info" id="h3Fourth">More Details:
            <br> <a href="">https://www.tv-wot.com</a>
          </h3>
        </div>

        <div id="movieSelect">
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="control">
        <form id="mainForm" action="">
          <input id="mainInput" type="text" name="movieSearch">
          <button id="btn">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```